# Proof Verification: What is the order of the product group $G\times G'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G,G'$ be groups. What is the order of the product group $G\times G'$?

Let $\mid G\mid =g$, $\mid G'\mid =g'$

The answer is $gg'$. But why? I tried in the following way:

Let $1'\in G'$ be the identity of $G'$. Now we immediately get two things:

1. $G\times \{1'\}$ is subgroup of $G\times G'$.
2. Order of $G\times \{1'\}$ is order of $G$, which is $g$.

Now index,$[G\times G' : G\times \{1'\}]=g'$. Then $\mid G\times G'\mid =gg'\space\space\space\space\blacksquare$

Is this okay? Or there may be easier way.

> **Note:** Multiplication of pairs by the rule in $G\times G'$ is defined in this way: $$(a,a'),(b,b')\dashrightarrow (ab,a'b')$$
>
> for $a,b\in G$ and $a',b'\in G'$.

Comment: You argument seems fine to me.. But you need not complicate something as easy as a Cartesian Product by bringing in things like Index of a subgroup. Always try to keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: @Naive thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters not that you're dealing with groups.  One simply needs to argue through the fact that $|A\times B|=|A||B|$ for any two sets $A$ and $B$ and that the cardinality of this direct product is infinite if either $|A|$ or $|B|$ is infinite.

Why is this the case?  Well, $|A\times B|=|\{(a,b)\ :\ a\in A, b\in B\}|$.  Use basic counting principles here.  How many choices for the first coordinate?  exactly $|A|$.  How many choices for the second coordinate?  exactly $|B|$.  Therefore, $|A\times B|=|A|\cdot |B|$.  It is clear that if either $|A|$ or $|B|$ is infinite then $|A\times B|$ is infinite since then there are infinite options for either the first or second coordinate (or both).  No need to monkey with homomorphisms.  Just count.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a group is its cardinality, which in this case will be the cardinality of the Cartesian product $G \times G'$, which is $|G||G'|$ - assuming both $G$ and $G'$ have finite order. If either should have infinite order, then theirdirect product will as well, since the Cartesian product of an infinite set with any nonempty set is infinite.

Comment: I guess what are you saying is which I did elaborately in my post.

Comment: I'm not sure about that - I think this is a genuinely simpler way. I had no need to invoke subgroups or the index of a subgroup. It simply follows from the definition of the direct product and elementary set theory.

Comment: I guess you don't understand what I am saying... I need a full proof or at least some relevant step.. apart from what I did, if their is a easy way... your answer do not show the full proof or at least some relevant step ... (for example showing isomorphism with $G\times G'$ with a group with order $gg'$ is a answer other than what I did.)

Comment: my point is you could write this in comment section instead of giving as a answer.

Comment: Explain why my answer is not a full proof. I will elaborate more if necessary.

Comment: Why the cardinality of the Cartesian product is $\mid G\mid \mid G'\mid$?

Comment: The cardinality of the Cartesian product of two finite sets is the product of their cardinalities.

Comment: I guess $g,g'$ can be infinite.

Comment: If either $G$ or $G'$ is of infinite order, I think it is clear that their direct product will also be infinite. I'll edit this case to the original answer.